# Set headers using variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a complete beginner at php and i'm having trouble with setting headers using php variables. I have used mysql database to store the filename, path, type, and size of the file then I stored the file in a folder. Then I stored it in a php variable. It downloads the file but I can't open the file. It also doesn't read the size properly. I have tried to search for solutions but it got me nowhere. Below is the code for downloading the file:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rems");
    if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM contract";         
    $result3 = (mysqli_query($db, $query3));
    if ($result3) {
        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result3)) {
            $name = $obj->File_Name;
            $path = $obj->File_Path;
            $type = $obj->File_Type;
            $size = $obj->File_Size;

            header('Content-Type: '.$type);
            header('Content-Length: '.$size);
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
            readfile($path);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result3);
    }
```

?>

Comment: Do you really think that a title consisting of repeating PHP is going to be useful, especially when there is *already* a PHP tag on the post?

Comment: This will try to download all the contracts, not just one.  Is that your intent?

Comment: I'm very sorry for that

Comment: There is only 1 row stored in the contract table. Is my way of using it not recommended?

Comment: What is the problem here? It's not clear what your specific issue is. "Can't open the file" means what? Is it empty? `readfile` can fail and you don't test for errors.

Comment: tadman, it says that there are problems with the contents and is unreadable when I try to open it. Also, the size is only 200Bytes when the uploaded file is 29.6Kb. But the file name and the extension are correct.